# TDD Mock validate.ValidateAsync method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I writing my unit test and we have method which call manual validation with passing `RuleSet` name.

I am not able to mock my `IValidator<RequestObj>.ValidateAsync()` method.

Sample mock statement I used

```
mockValidator.Setup(x => x.ValidateAsync(It.IsAny<SampleRequest>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(), It.IsAny<IValidatorSelector>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
             .ReturnsAsync(new ValidationResult());
```

I am getting following error

> Invalid setup on an extension method: x =>
>   x.ValidateAsync(It.IsAny(),
>   It.IsAny(), It.IsAny(),
>   It.IsAny())    at
>   Moq.Mock.ThrowIfSetupExpressionInvolvesUnsupportedMember(Expression
>   setup, MethodInfo method)

Please advise me on the correct approach.

Comment: _"Please advise me on the correct approach"_ - perhaps not to use mocking or at least any test code as complex as that.  _How to test the test code?_

Comment: yes, you don't need to mock but if your validation is complex it is handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can mock the Validate.ValidateAsync.

The Reason I was getting the error is I tried to mock an extension method. Whose method signature is

```
public static Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync<T>(this IValidator<T> validator, T instance, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken), IValidatorSelector selector = null, string ruleSet = null)
```

But If you see its implementation it calls

```
validator.ValidateAsync((ValidationContext) validationContext, cancellationToken);
```

So creating Mock based on the above signature solves the issue.

```
mockValidator.Setup(x => x.ValidateAsync(It.IsAny<ValidationContext>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                             .ReturnsAsync(new ValidationResult());
```

If you want to pass validation errors

```
mockValidator.Setup(x => x.ValidateAsync(It.IsAny<ValidationContext>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                             .ReturnsAsync(new ValidationResult(new List<ValidationFailure>()
                             {
                                 new ValidationFailure("TestField","Test Message"){ErrorCode = "1001"}
                             }));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you